# How to use b-roll to give more depth to the script

Tags: footage

I realize there are 2 ways to illustrate a script with stock footage.

One way is to simply use footage that matches what the script is about, for example for a script that talks about being rich, the footage would show a man with many banknotes and a luxury car. That would turn into a boring illustration because it shows what we already know.

The other way is to use footage that correspond to a thought with an extra step and... this is the a concept I don't fully understand so I would like you to explain it, with many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Privy Seal

(A privy is a slang UK english word for a toilet.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frost_Report#%22Lord_Privy_Seal%22

Charlie Brooker - How to report the news:

Watch all of Adam Curtis.  Love him or hate him, he knows how to use B-roll... It's all B-roll!

It's all about taste, and deciding what feels right in your video. There are conventions, but not rules.  I highly recommend the book [In the Blink of an Eye by Walter Murch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Blink-Eye-2nd-PerspectIve-Editing-ebook/dp/B08LS9WHW3/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=in%20the%20blink%20of%20an%20eye%20book&qid=1667919618&sr=8-1).

It won't teach you any Adobe Premiere Shortcuts.  It *will* make you think about how you edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would prefer something more readily applicable in my next youtube video. The first 2 videos are what not to do, Adam Curtis' documentaries are far from tutorials and the for book, maybe you could specify a chapter ?